# Add array elements into variable in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I stored some settings in array in Twig and I need to store them into some variable so I can print it. My array contains some data attributes like this:

```
{% set data = {
    visible:    { data: "data-visible-items", value: options.visible_items },
    scroll: { data: "data-itemes-scroll", value: options.items_to_scroll },
    speed: { data: "data-animation-speed", value: options.animation_speed },
    infinite: { data: "data-infinite", value: options.infinite },
    autoplay: { data: "data-autoplay", value: options.autoplay_enable },
    interval: { data: "data-autoplay-interval", value: options.autoplay_interval },
    hover: { data: "data-autoplay-hover", value: options.autoplay_hover },
} %}
```

Simply I want to store everything from array in one variable, in this variable it's need to be stored like this (separator is space) for example:

```
data-visible-items="5" data-items-scroll="2" data-animation-speed="400" data-infinite="0" data-autoplay="1" data-autoplay-interval="3000" data-autoplay-hover="1"
```

So, if the variable is for example **attributes** I just want to print it like this:

```
<div{{ attributes}}>
// Content
</div>
```

I wrote for loop like this:

```
{% for item in data %}
    {{ item.data }} {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

and it will print each data and value, but how to store this in the variable in the way I described above?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to transform that array you could make use of a `Twig_Filter` or `Twig_Function`

1. just chain [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query)

<kbd>PHP</kbd>

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('http_build_query', http_build_query', ['is_safe' => [ 'html', ],]));
```

<kbd>Twig</kbd>

```
<div{{ http_build_query(attributes, '', ' ') }}>
```

2. Create the string yourself with a foreach

<kbd>PHP</kbd>

```
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('build_attribute_list', function (array $array) {
    $str = '';
    foreach($array as $key => $val) $str .= ' '.$key.'="'.$val.'"';
    return $str;
}, ['is_safe' => ['html'],]);
```

<kbd>Twig</kbd>

```
<div{{ attributes|build_attribute_list }}>
```

---

*(edit)* Needless to say you can store the output in a variable as well

```
{% set my_var = attributes|build_attribute_list %}
{{ my_var }}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store into a variable you can do this:

```
{% for item in data %}
    {% set myvar = item.data ~ ' ' ~ item.value %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Variable `myvar` does not exist outside the loop and you overwriting it each time and thus not creating a string with all the variables inside it

Comment: As the OP said, he wants to print the var using something like <div{{ var}}> so he can do this in the loop, he doesn't specify he wants to store it outside loop...

Comment: Quoted from OP's question, `Simply I want to store everything from array in one variable, in this variable`